# filter-spec in wildfly 10

Tags: logging, filter, wildfly-10

Requirement :

```
         To filter error message/exception into another log named errorlog.log other than server.log
```

Configuration :

```
<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="errorjohn">
        <level name="ERROR"/>
<filter-spec value="match(&quot;UT005023:*&quot;)"/> 
        <formatter>
            <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="errorlog.log"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
<logger category="errortest" use-parent-handlers="false">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="errorjohn"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>
```

Error In server Log:

17:23:45,696 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-4) UT005023: Exception ha
ndling request to /Testsporacle/testing: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.nfr.sv

No error starting with UT005023: is logged in errorlog.log.
ApplicationServer used: wildfly 10.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing the category in subsystem logged the file.

```
<logger category="io.undertow.request" use-parent-handlers="false">
        <level name="ERROR"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
            <handler name="errorjohn"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem might be in the expression.  I believe it is a standard Java regex, meaning it should end with `.*` rather than `*`.